# is IFrame crawled by Google?

Tags: iframe, web-crawler

I have iframe that it is source is got from servlet response, so does the content of the iframe will be crawled?

Comment: in case of rendering HTML content in jquery  "$(document).ready(function()" does this content will be crawled?

Comment: no. javascript is client side so it wont be crawled.

Answer (score 2):

Google does crawl the framed content now. Just not sure yet how much equity is passed to the links.

http://www.seroundtable.com/google-iframe-link-14558.html
http://www.rimmkaufman.com/blog/do-search-engines-follow-links-in-iframes/31012012/

What Google surely stil not do is associating the framed content with the parent page. So your pagerank will not be influenced.

Answer (score 1):

No I'm pretty sure Google doesn't. The robot could end up in an endless loop!

**EDIT**: I followed the link given in the comment to the question. Although I see the test that was carried out appears to index the content of the iFrame, I think what is more likely is that it takes the URL of the iframe follows that and then indexes that page separately rather than actually doing it in the iframe. That way it could eliminate the possibility of an endless loop ie it could detect if the iframe was pointing at it's parent document.

Comment: what about the above comment?

Comment: Google supports frames and iframes https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34445

Answer (score -1):

Google crawling your iFramed content will not do anything for your PageRank. It would be great if I could iFrame KimKardashian.com on my website and have all the collateral search traffic on my site. This does not happen because the HTML source of the framed site does not show up on your html source.

However, I think that with Googles new Panda algorithm that is sophisticated on its concentration of user experience will favor your website if you iframe a popular, high-content website. This is just speculation, but google may follow the link in the iframe src="link" to the high-content site, and then give "points" to your website for enhancing user experience.

I came up with this idea reading articles like this :  http://www.entrepreneur.com/blog/223765