# Can I add rel nofollow to iframe tag?

Tags: iframe, seo

I have a widget distributed in some sites via an iframe. But I don't want the google bot index the url. Will adding a `nofollow` to `iframe` tag resolve the problem?. Does `Iframe` tag support `nofollow`, and will Google understand it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Absolutely, you kind of can add `rel="nofollow"` to an iframe. You just must be tricky about it. Here's how...

Build a blank html file. Add your iframe to that alone. In the Meta tag include

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
```

Now, iframe that page onto the one your going to show.

Answer (score 3):

[According to Google](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag), all you need is

```
<meta name="robots" content="none" />
```

“none - Equivalent to noindex, nofollow”

Answer (score 2):

The `rel` attribute is not allowed for the `iframe` element.

See allowed attributes for `iframe`: [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-iframe-element.html#the-iframe-element), [HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/frames.html#h-16.5)

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible but there is a workaround for it. You can use a URL of your domain that redirects to the IFRAME. In your robots.txt, you will prevent the bots to follow the link of your URL.

In your robots.txt add

```
User-agent:*
Disallow:/h/
```

Then, create a 301 redirect in your htaccess or something similar if you use something else like nginx. that will redirect a local URL to the URL of the Iframe.

```
Redirect 301 /h/fancy-url/ http://targetdomain.com/the-uri-of-iframe/
```

In your iframe use the

```
<iframe src="https://yourdomain.com/h/fancy-url/?possibleparam=xx">
```

Answer (score 0):

"rel" is not a recognised attribute for the "iframe" tag according to W3C specs. You could use some javascript and document.write to place the iframe code on the page

Answer (score 0):

you might want to check out [is IFrame crawled by Google?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101007/is-iframe-crawled-by-google) but from my understanding the "nofollow" is not allowed on an iframe

Answer (score 0):

Lazy load helps not to index iframe

`<iframe loading="lazy" src="xyz" />`